# What code lengths can optimal prefix codes assign to the symbols in a given probability distribution?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, bounds

***(Notation)*** Consider a finite alplhabet $\Sigma\equiv \{x_1,...,x_n\}$, corresponding to a probability distribution $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$. I want to encode this using a uniquely decodable binary code.
Let $\ell_i$ denote the length such code assigns to the $x_i$.

***(Context)*** From Shannon's theorem, we know that the average expected word length, in the ideal case, equals $H(P)\equiv \sum_i p_i \log(1/p_i)$. More generally, if an encoding is optimal, then the expected word length $\mathbb E[S]$ is such that
$$H(P) \le \mathbb E[S] \le H(P) + 1.\tag1$$
We know that [Huffman's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is an example of an optimal uniquely decodable binary code, and thus must give an expected word length satisfying (1).

***(Question)*** I suppose we should therefore expect that, for any given distribution, Huffman's coding assigns lengths such that $\ell_i\sim \log(1/p_i)$. In general, however, this will not be an identity.
Is there a way to make this statement more precise? In other words, can we assign precise bounds to the lengths $\ell_i$ that an optimal code such as Huffman's associates to a given probability distribution?

Or even better, is there a way to estimate the lengths $\ell_i$ that are actually assigned by an optimal encoding to a given probability distribution?

***(More precise formulation of the question)*** To be more precise, I am asking about whether there are "easily computable" functions $m_i(\vec p),M_i(\vec p)$ such that an optimal coding of the probabilities $\vec p\equiv(p_1,...,p_n)$ produces lengths $\ell_i$ such that:
$$m_i(\vec p) \le \ell_i \le M_i(\vec p).$$
What "easily computable" means is left vague, but I'm thinking about nontrivial bounds: *e.g.*, computing $m_i,M_i$ must not involve passing through the Huffman coding procedure itself, and the bounds should be telling us something useful (something like $m_i(\vec p)> 0$ would be an example of a not-so-useful bound).

Not knowing much about the feasibility of this, I'm not sure what more to ask about such bounds. Things that come to mind are:

1. whether there are bounds that only depend on the entropy of the distribution (that would amount to ask for $m_i(H),M_i(H)$ such that $m_i(H(\vec p))\le \ell_i(\vec p)\le M_i(H(\vec p))$ for any $\vec p$ with a given entropy).
2. bounds that only depend on the individual probabilities: some $m_i=m_i(p_i)$ and $M_i=M_i(p_i)$ such that $m_i(p_i)\le \ell_i(\vec p) \le M_i(p_i)$ for any probability distribution $\vec p$.

Comment: Bounds in terms of what? Huffman coding length can come arbitrarily close to the entropy by coding sequences of letters rather than individual letters.

Comment: @whuber do you mean encoding something like $\Sigma^{\times m}$ for $m$ large? I suppose that makes sense, but I was thinking about the encoding of the single letters (after all, encoding sequences of letters can be thought of as encoding single "letters", with the new letters being tuples, no?). Bounds in terms of some properties of the distribution (I don't think there is any other type of information that is relevant in this context, or is there?)

Comment: The relevant property of the distribution would be the expected length of the result of applying the Huffman coding algorithm to it!

Comment: @whuber I mean, obviously, but I'm talking about whether there are bounds that can be easily computed and stated without having to compute the coding itself. We know that $\ell_i$ should be somewhat close to $\log(1/p_i)$, correct? So isn't there something that can be said about how far $\ell_i$ can be from $\log(1/p_i)$, for example? For example, if $p_i=2^{-r_i}$ with $r_i\in\mathbb N$ for all $i$, then I think $\ell_i=\log(1/p_i)$ is exact, no? So isn't there some quantitative way to easily see how much a distribution is far from being like this?

Comment: @whuber though there is one thing that I suppose I was assuming but might not be correct. Am I correct in saying that any optimal uniquely decodable code assigns the same (module insignificant reorderings of symbols with same probabilities) code lengths to the symbols attached to a given probability distribution?

Comment: That's incorrect.  The optimal prefix code tends to assign words of length close to $-\log_2 p_i$ to symbols having probability $p_i.$  But that's only a tendency: there can be strong discrepancies.  As an example, when one of the $p_i$ is much smaller than any of the others, its code word will tend to be much shorter than $-\log_2 p_i.$

Comment: @whuber well now I'm confused. But the average word length ($\mathbb E[S]$ in the question) does not change as long as the prefix code is optimal, no? So what you are saying is that different optimal prefix codes will give same average word length, but different individual word lengths. But if two codes assign different lengths at symbols with different probabilities, how can they result in the same expected word length? (unless I'm misunderstanding what you are saying is incorrect)

Comment: It helps to compute examples. Consider a code for three probabilities $(1/2,1/2-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is tiny. One optimal code is (`0`, `01`, `11`). Notice that two extremely different probabilities, $1/2-\epsilon$ and $\epsilon,$ nevertheless get the same word length. This is also an optimal code for the distribution $(2/5,2/5,1/5),$ providing another interesting example.

Comment: @whuber ok but what does that show? Different probabilities can correspond to different optimal word lengths, I get that. Still, the optimal word length associated with a given probability distribution does not depend on using Huffman coding or something else, no? E.g. for $n=5$, if I plot the Huffman lengths associated to each probability (randomly sampling probabilities of given size), I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/34KXj.png. This shows how e.g. you cannot have $\ell_i=4$ unless $p_i\lessapprox 0.2$. This is the type of bounds I'm thinking about

Comment: here's the same for $n=10$ probabilities, overlayed with the function $\log(1/x)$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yillh.png. Clearly you cannot say thing such as $\ell_i\lessgtr \log(1/p_i)$, but there are bounds that might be computable

Comment: By definition, "optimal word length" is unique: you can't have two different optima!  My examples illustrate claims I made in earlier comments.  I don't believe your graph, because any outcome with a probability of, say, 0.2, will *never* be (optimally) encoded with a word of length 4.  The upper bound length is $\lceil -\log_2 p_i\rceil.$

Comment: @whuber *By definition, "optimal word length" is unique: you can't have two different optima!* indeed, that's exactly what I was saying above. I suppose when you said "that's incorrect" you referred to something else then. *I don't believe your graph (...)* indeed, I never get 0.2, but I get arbitrarily close to it. That corresponds e.g. to distributions $(0.4,0.2,0.2,0.2-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ with small $\epsilon>0$. "*The upper bound length is*" that's pretty much what I was looking for. How do you see that that is the case?

Comment: @whuber "*The upper bound length is $\lceil-\log_2 p_i\rceil$*" actually, I don't understanding this statement. Consider again $(0.4,0.2,0.2,0.2-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. With it, you get that $0.199$ is assigned code length $4$. However, $\log_2(1/0.199)\approx 2.3$, and thus $\lceil \log_2(1/p_i)\rceil = 3$, which contradicts the length actually being $4$ in this case for $0.199$. I similarly get, for probability distributions of length $n=5$, max probs of 1/5 for $\ell=4$, of 1/3 for $\ell=3$, and 1/2 for $\ell=2$.

Comment: In your example an optimal prefix code is (`0`, `100`, `101`, `110`, `111`) with expected length $(2/5)(1)+(3/5)(3)=11/5 = 2.2.$  Depending on $\epsilon,$ the entropy is between $1.922$ and $2.122.$  Regardless, *no outcome gets a code of length 4.*

Comment: @whuber because you are pairing second and third 0.2 at the second iteration I suppose? Fine, consider then $(0.4,0.2+\epsilon/2,0.2-\epsilon/2,0.2-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. This has optimal prefix code `0`,`10`,`110`,`1110`,`1111`, no?

Comment: That's a great example, thank you.  It supports my initial instinct that the answer is difficult and might be tantamount to just finding the optimal code in the first place ;-).